# Problem after transaction commit failed

Tags: qt, postgresql, transactions

I inserted entity "a" into table with unique column content. Then

```
Db.driver().commitTransaction()
```

Then begin new transaction and repeated. Transaction failed. As I can guess next action is automatic transacion rollback. Then I tried

```
Dlg.Table.model().select()
```

but it returned 0 rows (although there are several rows in table). Why? How to fix this?

EDIT: No, rollback have to be done manually.

Comment: Why downvote? I'll try not to repeat this mistake in the future

Comment: You need to post more code for somebody to be able to answer this. Right now this is completely out of context.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution that I have found is using something like this function:

```
def refresh_model(Dlg):
    Dlg.Model = QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    Dlg.Model.setTable(Dlg.TableName)
    Dlg.Model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    for Col in range(len(DisplColNames[Dlg.TableName])):
        Dlg.Model.setHeaderData( Col, Qt.Horizontal, DisplColNames[Dlg.TableName][Col])
    Dlg.tvTable.setModel(Dlg.Model)
    Dlg.Model.select()
```

But why I need to set new model after fail of transaction is unclear.